# Maven can't resolve dependency with some specific version of jar

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository, aem

I try to get some specific version of jar from public adobe repository:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.adobe.granite.asset.api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

There are 3 versions that I can see in repository:

- 1.4
- 1.6
- 2.0.4

But Maven can get only 1.4 and 1.6, when I try to get 2.0.4 maven throws exception:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.adobe.granite:com.adobe.granite.asset.api:jar:2.0.4.
```

Does anybody know what have I missed?

Comment: Can you post the whole error Maven is giving?

Comment: I think I understood what is wrong. com.adobe.granite.asset.api-2.0.4.pom uses `<parent><groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId><artifactId>parent</artifactId><version>33</version><relativePath/></parent>` but this parent doesn't exist in adobe repository.

Comment: So, in my case I have to download available jar with needed version and provide it to my project?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download "parent" project for asset.api and then insall it in your local repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-file -DpomFile=path-to-pomfile
```

If you will not find jar "parent" with version 33 which is required by com.adobe.granite.asset.api you can download from adobre repository parent with version 32 and locally change it version to 33